# Euclidean algorithm pseudocode: prove that if m>n then m mod n < m/2.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have the following pseudocode and I am supposed to show that if m>n then m mod n < m/2. Then I am supposed to show that the running time for the code is O(log, n) as n approaches infinity. I can tell that the code is pseudocode for the Euclidean algorithm. For the second part - I have no idea why. I would imagine the running time would vary depending on how many "rounds" would have to be completed in order to find the greatest common divisor. For the first part I suppose I have to treat the following separately: the case where m ≥ 2n and the case where n < m < 2n. I don't know how to continue from that though.

gcd( m, n ) { 
while( n != 0 ) { 
long rem = m % n; 
m = n; 
n = rem; 
}
return m;
}

Comment: Given that $m\bmod n<n$, if $m\bmod n\geq m/2$, then $n>m/2$. Is that possible?

Comment: If $n\le m/2$, then $m\mod n<n\le m/2$. If $n>m/2$, then $m \mod n=m-n<m/2$.

Comment: Your pseudocode ain't correct. Why do you return $m$?

Comment: The code is given in the question. Why do you say it's incorrect? It simply goes through the remainder of m%n until it is 0 and returns the GCD. No?

Comment: The code returns m because it is the last common divisor where n != 0, which is the GCD. When m is returned, n = 0, so it would not make sense to return n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can say $m = qn + r$ with $q$ an integer and $0 \leq r < n$ the remainder. We know $q \geq 1$ since $m > n$.

Note that $r < n$ implies $r < \frac{n+r}{2} \leq \frac{qn+r}{2} = \frac{m}{2}$, so we are done.

Answer (score 4):

For the proof part, I agree with you separate into cases and analyze.
1. m > 2n, then n < m/2, it is clear that (m mod n) < n < m/2
2. n < m < 2n, then m = n + r for some r < n, so (m mod n) = r = m - n.
   because m/2 < n, so m - n < m/2. Hence (m mod n) < m/2.